# Lifetime of a ServiceClient for C2D messages

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We are investigating an issue with our solution a azure function with eventhub ingress that sends C2D messages over IoT hub.

We did hit a Throttle limit

```
he request has been throttled. Wait 10 seconds and try again. Operation type: AmqpLinkOpen Tracking
```

But when the limit was hit once, for each following message we did hit the same throttle exception, no new messages where sent C2D.

After a restart of the function the messages where picked up again, it seams that the service client was initialized once at startup of the function.

Is the statement correct that we should initiate a new ServiceClient for each C2D message we would like to send?

Comment: This sounds like a valid issue to open in the official github repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've added it to the github project https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/1189